# Generalization of degree of a map (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

Let $f:M\to N$ be a continuous map between two oriented manifolds of dimension $n$. There are a lot of alternative definitions of degree, but I'm only interested in the following one. Since $M,N$ are oriented, that means that $H_n(M)=H_n(N)=\mathbb{Z}.$ So the induced map in homology
$$
f_\ast:H_n(M)\cong \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{d}\mathbb{Z}\cong H_n(N)
$$
is multiplication by an integer $d$, which we call the degree.

Next, I would like to generalize this definition to manifolds that are not oriented. There's an obvious way to do this. Let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime, and let $f:M\to N$ be a map between manifolds such that $H_n(M)= H_n(N)= \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$ Then
$$
f_\ast:H_n(M)\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{[d]}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\cong H_n(N)
$$
is multiplication by some $[d]\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},$ which I'm calling mod p degree.

This seems like such an immediately useful idea that somebody has to have done it before. But I don't know where in the literature to look.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Edit: Cross-posted to Math Overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380695/references-for-this-generalisation-of-degree-of-a-map).

Comment: This question is something between math stack exchange and math overflow... So maybe it's could be a good idea to publish the same question on math overflow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've done that.

Comment: If $p\neq2$ and $M,N$ unorientable, then $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=H_n(N;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=0$, so this only really makes sense for $p=2$. This is known as the mod 2 degree. The only place I know mentioning it (though in the setting of differential topology) is Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you! At the moment, I'm mainly interested in the p=2 case. The motivation is to find a neccessary condition for a space X to (stably) factorise as X = M^p \vee something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only interesting for $p=2$, and this is indeed the mod-2 degree. Searching for this should give you many references.

For a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ between non-orientable manifolds you can sometimes refine the mod-2 degree and orient the map $f$ instead of the manifolds. You get a notion of twisted degree. I think this is due to Paul Olum, perhaps in the paper below.

> MR0058212 (15,338a) Reviewed
> Olum, Paul
> Mappings of manifolds and the notion of degree.
> Ann. of Math. (2) 58 (1953), 458–480.
> 56.0X